# What happens when a script is called immediately below a div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile-listview

I have just distilled my problem to as simple as this

```
 <div id="case-schedule">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Mail</li>
        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Contacts</li>
        <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
    <script>
    function case-shedule() {
    }
    </script>
```

When i remove function definition content is loading properly. however when i try to include a function 
(just an empty one) i am not getting jquery mobile "look and feel".
whats happening when a script is called immediately below a div tag? does that exclude the other Js files? included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function name is invalid... most likely causing the js in the page to fail. Valid variable  (and function) names don't include the 'minus' character.

Try:

```
function caseshedule(){

}
```